# Float Layout with fixed width and one expanding element

Tags: html, css

I would like to do something like this:

Prefix - Input(Type: Text, Number,..) - Suffix - Button

```css
ul
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
input[type=number] 
{ 
    width: 100%; 
}
input[type=button] 
{ 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.value
{
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.ok
{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="prefix">
                    prefix
                </td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="number" size="1"/>
                </td>
                <td class="sufix">
                    suffix
                </td>
                <td class="ok">
                    <input type="button" value="val1"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="prefix">
                    pre
                </td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="number" size="1"/>
                </td>
                <td class="sufix">
                    suf
                </td>
                <td class="ok">
                    <input type="button" value="longervalue"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="prefix">
                    pre
                </td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="number" size="1"/>
                </td>
                <td class="sufix">
                    suf
                </td>
                <td class="ok">
                    <input type="button" value="v"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have a fixed width within this 4 things have to be placed.

I don't know the Prefix, Suffix and also not the Text of the Button.

I would like that all those 3 elements use the minimal possible space and the width of the inputtag fills up this place.

Is this possible?

I would not like to use a table or JS **IF POSSIBLE**

Comment: you can use divs (give them specific width which you want) instead of tables and make input tag width 100%

Comment: I would like them to use the minim possible width..

Comment: if you wan to allign all fields vertically use defined width lets say 
......
`<div style="width:'30px'"> sufix </div>
  <div style="width:'50px'"> <input tag /> </div>
  <div style="width:'80px'"> <input button /> </div>`  

for all elements or else don't defined width of divs

Comment: @MisterPresident Does my answer solves your problem?

Comment: no because you use fixed widths :(

Comment: No, I did not used fixed widths. Check this **[jsfiddle with the basic css](http://jsfiddle.net/pgay6otr/4/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Flexbox layout.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Given this html:

```
<section>
  <label>pre</label>
  <input type="number" size="1"/>
  <label>suf</label>
  <input type="button" value="longervalue"/>
</section>
```

All you need is:

```
section {
  display: flex;
}

input[type=number] {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgay6otr/3/)**

Comment: nearly perfect but when i resize it suddenly the button gets smaller even if the input tag could get smaller?

Comment: @MisterPresident Did you test my jsFiddle? The buttons don't change at all.

Comment: In Chrome they do, in Firefox not?

Comment: @MisterPresident I have tested in Chrome and Firefox and both are fine. Are you testing my fiddle or your code?

Comment: that's stange. Did you also test it with a very small width? because first it works and than it resizes,..

Comment: @MisterPresident Well that's not a bug, that's expected behavior, because the three `section` elements share the same width `100%`. When the widest section (the 2nd) cannot shrink no more, the other two continue to shrink. If this sounds confusing remove two sections, and test only with one. I am using `section { width: 100%; }` for demonstration purposes only. If you change it to `300px` you will not have that problem.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but I didn't understand: Look at that example: The Textbox still could get smaller: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgay6otr/5/)

Comment: @MisterPresident Nothing changes because the `section` parent container has a fixed width of 200px (see line 4 of your CSS). In this context, resizing the window does nothing. Change that line to `width: 100px` and you will see a shorter textbox. Remember that `flex-grow` expands all the way to occupy the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Use belo code

```
<style>
ul
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
input[type=number] 
{ 
    width: 100%; 
}
input[type=button] 
{ 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.value
{
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.ok
{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="prefix">
                    prefix
                </td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="number" size="1"/>
                </td>
                <td class="sufix">
                    suffix
                </td>
                <td class="ok">
                    <input type="button" value="val1"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="prefix">
                    pre
                </td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="number" size="1"/>
                </td>
                <td class="sufix">
                    suf
                </td>
                <td class="ok">
                    <input type="button" value="longervalue"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="prefix">
                    pre
                </td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="number" size="1"/>
                </td>
                <td class="sufix">
                    suf
                </td>
                <td class="ok">
                    <input type="button" value="v"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
```